# Given $\mathbb{N}_{CF}$, let $A\subset\mathbb{N}$ be a finite set such that $A\neq \emptyset$. Prove: $\mathbb{N}_{CF}\diagup A \cong \mathbb{N}_{CF}$

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

Given $\mathbb{N}_{CF}$, the cofinite topology on $\mathbb{N}$. let $A\subset\mathbb{N}$ be a finite set such that $A\neq \emptyset$.

Prove: $\mathbb{N}_{CF}\diagup A \cong \mathbb{N}_{CF}$
hence, the quotient space $\mathbb{N}_{CF}\diagup A$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{N}_{CF}$

I'm not sure I understand what needs to be proved. if $A$ is finite, then $|\mathbb{N}\setminus A| = |\mathbb{N}$, as $A\neq \emptyset$,and $A$ is finite, why is the argument not immediate by cardinality considerations?

Comment: "I don't even understand how the quotient space is defined". Did you look at the definition of a quotient space before posting your question?

Comment: (-1) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_space_(topology)

Comment: @AnneBauval - Of course I did. I don't understand how the quotient space for this question is defined, and as I read the definition and tried to figure it out - but failed to do so  - I posted the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$|\Bbb N\setminus A|=|\Bbb N|$$

Isn't the whole story. For two spaces to be homeomorphic, it is necessary *but not at all sufficient* that the underlying sets have the same cardinality. For example, if you give the set $\{0,1\}$ the discrete topology, the trivial topology and the Sierpinski space topology, you have three spaces of equal cardinality and all of them are distinct: no one is homeomorphic to the other. A more interesting example is that the unit circle $S^1$ is not homeomorphic to $[0,1)$ despite there being a continuous bijection $[0,1)\to S^1$.

The quotient space is defined here how it is always defined:

> $\Bbb N/A$ has point set the set $(\Bbb N\setminus A)\sqcup\{A\}$ where $\{A\}$ is just a canonical way to adjoint a singleton. Ordinarily I'd just write $\ast$ for some arbitrary single point, which is to represent $A$. We write $q:\Bbb N\to\Bbb N/A$ as the map $n\mapsto n$ - if $n\notin A$ - and $n\mapsto\{A\}$ - if $n\in A$.
>
> The topology on $\Bbb N/A$ is precisely the set of all $U$ for which $q^{-1}(U)$ is open in $\Bbb N$.

That definition is formally precise but also a little unwieldy. Just think of $\Bbb N/A$ as the space you get when you take $\Bbb N$ and 'continuously' squash $A$ down to a single point, but leave everything else the same. Neighbourhoods of this new single point must un-squash to neighbourhoods of the set $A$.

Hopefully that clears things up.

As for the exercise, here is a hint:

> The map $q$ has a certain special property, that whenever $X$ is any other space and $f:\Bbb N\to X$ is continuous, if $f$ is constant on $A$ then $f=gq$ for a unique continuous $g:\Bbb N/A\to X$. In particular if you want to find a homeomorphism with $\Bbb N$, it's actually sufficient to find a map $\Phi:\Bbb N\to\Bbb N$ with this same property (why? Think about taking $X:=\Bbb N$ and $X:=\Bbb N/A$).
>
> Think about $\Phi$ which involve bijections **of sets** $\Bbb N\setminus A\cong\Bbb N$. Does any such $\Phi$ have this property?

Comment: Can you elaborate about the hint? Why is the claim true? Also, it's not clear what $\Phi$ needs to satisfy

Comment: $\Phi$ needs to satisfy the ‘universal property’ I mentioned, about “for any $f$ … “. This is standard but actually overkill, we only need to consider the property for $f:=q$, but it’s helpful to think with the abstraction @BulGali

Comment: This pattern of thought is ‘categorical’. Its a way to create a map $\Bbb N/A\to\Bbb N$ that is a homeomorphism, which is maybe more confusing without this (common) thought process